# My firefox freeze when I access this site

Tags: firefox

http://www.redmondpie.com/ At least some page of it.

It seems that the page never stop loading. Some plugin problem.

I wonder if it happens on other people computer or is there something I should upgrade on my computer. It seems like a nice site teaching how to jailbreak iphones.

Answer (score 2):

The page (http://www.redmondpie.com) contains a LOT OF Facebook Like Plugins.

See this table for explanation (this is just a portion of all like-boxes):

[image: devmode-like-facebook-overflow]

Some of these requests take as many seconds as 1. This is totally unnatural for a page to load approx. 50 of these, which for me sums up to ~40sec page load just for the these plugins.

Also, in the background there are a lot more stuff going on.

**Summary:** This page's loading time depends heavily on your internet connection and your processor.

**EDIT:** I wanted to post a timeline summary, but my DevTools froze :P I managed to do it anyways, so here it is:

[image: devtools-summary-timeline]

**EDIT2:** See that *Scripting* time over there? Now that's not just internet. That is script compilation & execution, so it depends on your processor as well. (Updated summary)

Comment: I get a long load time as well.

Comment: it seems that it's more than just network issue. it's as if it forces firefox to run some plugin/program that take quite a chunk of CPU and then firefox becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

It's the site.  It wasn't written well.  My computer is a pretty top notch machine and it is still loading as I type this.  It finally did stop after a while.  You may want to disable your add-ons and extensions and then try it.  The rendering on the page does take a long time in comparison to other sites.

Comment: I don't think so. It loads in about 4 seconds in my firefox.

Comment: 4 seconds is still pretty long for a site to load.  It does spin for quite a while.  My google comes up instantly when searching.  Another way to track exactly why it is taking a long time would be to open the network tab in the developer mode.

Comment: Thats because of the network, it takes about the same time to load google search page too

Comment: When opening the Network tab in developer mode most of the requests the page is making takes 14 to 15 seconds to return.  (At least from where I am)

Answer (score 0):

The Redmond Pie website takes about two seconds to load in my Firefox with Adblock Plus extension installed and enabled. JavaScript is also enabled.

It appears that there is nothing wrong with the site, so what would happen if you tried to visit the site by opening a new Firefox window with a temporary profile?

1. Create a temporary folder for a temporary profile.
2. Run Firefox with argument `-profile path/to/temporary-folder -no-remote -new-instance`
3. You may delete a temporary profile after you close the Firefox instance.

To run Firefox in Windows with the argument, at the command prompt, type the following:

```
start firefox -profile c:\path\to\temporary-folder -no-remote -new-instance
```

Comment: There's no problem with me too. Firefox latest update, AdBlockPlus enabled but NoScript disabled